# Требуется ускорить работу кода

Tags: python

https://inf-ege.sdamgia.ru/problem?id=36000&print=true

задача с файлом отсюда

написал код :

```
with open ('26-2.txt') as f:
    n=int(f.readline())
    a=[int(s) for s in f]
a.sort()
sp=[]
for i in range(0,len(a)-1):
    for j in range(i+1,len(a)):
        if (a[i]%2==0 and a[j]%2!=0) or (a[i]%2!=0 and a[j]%2==0):
            if (a[i]+a[j]) in a:
                sp.append(a[i]+a[j])
print(len(sp),max(sp))
```

очень долго работает код, чисел в файле 5000

как ускорить код?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Сколько чисел в файле? Если пара тысяч, то просто проверяйте на вхождение в set.

Comment: @EzikBro добавил в вопрос

Comment: @EzikBro точно также долго грузит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такая програмка у меня отработала за полторы секунды на вашем файле:

```
with open('26.txt', 'r') as f:
    n = int(f.readline())
    a = [int(f.readline()) for _ in range(n)]

even = [i for i in a if i % 2 == 0]
odd = [i for i in a if i % 2 == 1]
s = set(a)

count, max_ = 0, 0
for i in even:
    for j in odd:
        if i + j in s:
            count += 1
            max_ = max(max_, i + j)

print(count, max_)
```

Comment: а почему с set() работает быстрее? ведь сет просто убирает все повторы, но и так сказано в задании  что числа различны? тогда почему выдает быстрее?

Comment: @Никита set - это другая структура данных, которая теряет порядок элементов, но позволяет быстро проверять, содержится ли определенный элемент во множестве, за счет особой реализации. Немного подробнее можете прочитать здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929284/what-makes-sets-faster-than-lists

Comment: @EzikBro А вот хорошо бы добавить это ваше пояснение про множества прямо в ответ. Проверка наличия элемента во множестве работает за `O(1)`, а в списке за `O(n)`, в этом суть.